# How can I run multiple programs sequentially, from one solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Visual studio solution containing multiple programs, each of which contains it's own Class and Main Method. I need to set these programs up to run one after the other, as some of them access the same database tables, and I do not want there to be conflicts.

I have tried setting up dependencies and creating a new program with class dependencies, however, this does not seem to have worked, does anyone have an idea?

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't your approach work?

Comment: Have you tried in Solution Explorer, right click Solution, Solution Properties->Common Properties->Startup Project and then click "Multiple Startup Projects"?

Also, can you provide the error you're seeing?

Comment: Apologies, I've editted the question and included a screenshot of the error.

I had already tried setting multiple startups, but with that approach, all the projects start together and causes the attached error.

Comment: If you're using an MS-Access database, be sure to open it in multi-user mode. Include ;Mode=16; in your connection string. And dont have the database open in access in single-user mode

Comment: I'm pulling data from an SQL-Server database and pushing to a visual foxpro database, will this connection user mode be accepted by foxpro?

Comment: I think you should add; Exclusive=No; instead of ;Mode=16;. Btw, I thought data was moved the opposite way, these days :)

Comment: You would be right, but who I'm writing this for uses a system written in foxpro, and they wanted me to pull data from SQL to their system =P

Though the system is slowly being rewritten...

Comment: Ok :). I think your problem is related to table-file locking and single-/multi- user problems. I think the syntax for foxpro connection strings is Exclusive=No. Or you can try Exclusive=false. Not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your solution > Properties > Common Properties > Startup project

Select "Multiple startup Projects" and change the value of the Action column from "None" to "Start" or "Start without debugging"

Comment: How does that stop there being conflicts in the database?

Comment: IMO only one project should have the responsability to acces to the database, and this project will be referenced in all the other project that need information from the database

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is a development tool. It is not a tool to orchestrate how your application should execute. Your application should also function when executed outside Visual Studio.

With that in mind you need to decide how to partition your application. Right now you seem to have several applications (console programs?) that need to execute one after the other. An easy solution is to create a batch file that executes each in turn. You can also create a separate application that execute each "child" application in sequence using the [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) method but why bother when you can create a batch file?

You might also consider merging your different applications into a single application that has a `Main` method that executes each task in sequence.

Without more information about your problem it is hard to give you specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you have tried "Multiple Startup Projects" approach but did you set the order in which multiple projects run when you start the debugger?

**To set the order in which multiple projects run when you start the debugger**

1. Open the Solution Property Pages dialog box.
2. Select the Startup Project set under Common Properties.
3. In the pane on the right, select Multiple Startup Project.
4. Select a project, and then click Move Up to run that project earlier when you start the debugger, or click Move Down to run the project later.

---

*Reference:* [How to: Modify Project Properties and Configuration Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z15yzzew.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You need run each program in separate Visual Studio instances.

Comment: How does that stop there being conflicts in the database?